# WebView don't response with button in JS

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to load a webView which embed JS code,then I want to click a button in the webView and the it can get some  param from server,then callback my android method.
I try it in test enviroment( Just Run As AndroidApplication ),it is work well,but when I singed a apk with my keystore, but it doesn't work ,the click event don't response,I think it is because there is some problem in the proguard.ctf,but I don't know the concrete reason,and there are some code about webView in my proguard.ctf

```
-keep class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface.** {*;}
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient
```

so thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting error because of proguard?

Comment: Yes ,and now I have fixed it , js code call my android method,I create a inner class including two method for callback by js code,maybe the method don't call in my application,so when I sign the apk ,it will proguard ,so the js can't find it ,the solution is add follow code: -keep class com.mypackage.activity.MyActivity$DemoJavaScriptInterface{           public <fields>;
 public <methods>;
}

Comment: Where the solution added ? Post your solution as answer.

Comment: I create a inner class named DemoJavaScriptInterface in my Activity ,and there are tow method in it for callling back .I avoid proguarding them while signing apk ,there are code I add in proguard.ctf ： `-keep class com.mypackage.activity.MyActivity$DemoJavaScriptInterface{ public <fields>; public <methods>; } `